# Gated check-in submit my change with error

Tags: build-process, build-automation, tfsbuild

i define build with gated check-in trigger but it does not work correctly.
for example, i have an error in controller or class so gated check-in must reject check-in and does not let me submit my change but submit my change and check-in successful.
i have an error in Person class when check-in this class,gated check-in must reject check-in but does not do it and submit my change.when in "items to build" property in process tab i add Person.cs, gated check-in work correct but i have more than 100 classes in my project and cant add all of these classes in items to build.

Comment: As is this is a little hard to answer - please provide more information about your setup including configuration details.

Comment: What are you building? A Solution with Projects?

Comment: yes i want to build solution with many projects

Comment: Create a build definition and define as "Items to build" only the solution (.sln file) you want to check. It will try to compile it and if it fails, the checkin will be rejected. You don't have to specify each class or project individually, they are included if they are part of the solution.

Comment: i did it.when i define solution as Items To Build, give me error about xcopy.how to solve this error?

Comment: i solve my xcopy problem but when i have an error in code and check-in changes,gated check-in must reject check-in operation but  submit my changes and check-in successfull.why?

Comment: also when define Configuration as "Debug/any cpu", build definition give me xcopy error but when Configuration define as "Debug/x64" does not give me error but give warning "Debug/x64" is invalid